# Select inside linq select

Tags: c#, entity-framework, linq

I have the following code (this is just relevant part):

```
linqQuery.Select(invoice =>
    new InvoiceDetailed 
    {
            UnpaidAmount = e.SumAmount +
            e.OverdueNotices.OrderByDescending(on => on.SendDate).Select(on => on.Fee).DefaultIfEmpty(0).Sum() +
            e.CreditNotes.Select(c => c.CreditNoteAmount).DefaultIfEmpty(0).Sum() -
            e.Payments.Select(p => p.Amount).DefaultIfEmpty(0).Sum()
    }
```

And this calculation for UnpaidAmount I repeat in severl other queries also. My question is if there is a way to somehow wrap that expression in function like:

```
Expression<Func<crmInvoice_Invoice, double>> unpaidExpression = // that unpaid amount caluculation expression
```

And then call like this:

```
    linqQuery.Select(invoice =>
    new InvoiceDetailed 
    {
            UnpaidAmount = unpaidExpression(invoice)
    }
```

Then I could reuse it in more queries. Is it possible to do something similar in LINQ? And if it is not is there any alternative solution u could suggest me to avoid repeating that part of code?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, it's impossible.
[`Select`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb548743(v=vs.110).aspx) method gets `Expression` as an argument. LINQ to SQL parses `Expression` to SQl code. So, to solve your task you need to convert you expression to return `InvoiceDetailed`:

```
Expression<Func<crmInvoice_Invoice, InvoiceDetailed>> InvoiceDetailedExpression = ...
```

Comment: Correct, though it should be noted that this applies to entity-framework which OP mentioned in tags. It would work as intended in LINQ operating on `IEnumerable<T>`.